# Getting "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" Error from Ionic-native VideoEditor Plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I'm developing an ionic app, where user can record a new video. Then I want to break the video into frames and send frames to a server. I'm using `createThumbnail` function from `ionic-native` `VideoEditor` plugin. But when I try to call `createThumbnail` function, it throws

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Here's my source code.

#### HTML Code

```
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button full (click)="captureVideo()">Capture video</button>
  <br/>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let file of mediaFiles" tappable (click)="playFile(file)" text-wrap>
      {{file.name}}
      <p>{{file.size/1000/1000 | number}} MB</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <video controls autoplay #myvideo></video>
</ion-content>
```

#### TypeScript Code

```
captureVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = {
      limit: 1,
      duration: 30
    }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options).then((res: MediaFile[]) => {

      let videoData = JSON.stringify(res);
      let res1 = JSON.parse(videoData);
      this.videoURL = res1[0]['fullPath'];
      
      let video = this.myvideo.nativeElement;
      video.src =  this.videoURL;
      video.play();

      var option: CreateThumbnailOptions = {
        fileUri: res[0].fullPath,
        outputFileName: 'aaaa',
        atTime: 2,
        width: 320,
        height: 480,
        quality: 100
      };
      console.log("option :" ,option);
      this.videoEditor.createThumbnail(option).then(res=>{
        console.log('Thumbnail result: ' + res);
      }).catch(err=>{
        console.log("ERROR ERROR", err)
      });

    }, (err) => {
      console.log("ERROR", "error selecting video");
    });
  }
```

Can someone help me with, why I'm getting such error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems ionic team has made some changes to their native plugins. You need to install the correct version of the native plugin corresponding to your project type. And import it correctly based on your angular version. All you need to do is,

Check your project type in **ionic.config.json** file.

If the type is "**ionic-angular**", then install 4.x.x version. In your case

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/video-editor@4.20.0
```

If the type is "**angular**", then install 5.x.x-beta version

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/video-editor@5.0.0-beta.24
```

**Note:**

Add ngx at the end of import only if you are using Angular 6

```
import { VideoEditor } from '@ionic-native/video-editor/ngx';
```

if not remove ngx from the import both in app.module.ts and app.component.ts

```
import { VideoEditor } from '@ionic-native/video-editor';
```

**Refencence**:https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074

Comment: This solution works for me. So the problem is with the plugin version.Thank you very much @Rathnakara S.