# Ionic Navigator Launch doesn't work. I click on button and nothing happens

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm struggling to develop a card that, when clicked, open any Maps app from the device, mainly using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHBLjRuzb7s

Although I coded the same code it's not working since nothing happens when I click the button.

This is my html file:

```
<div>
  <ion-card>
    <div>
      <img src="{{UnitLocal}}">
    </div>
    <ion-item>
      <button ion-button block (click)="navToMaps()">Universidade Tiradentes</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

And this is my ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'unitmap',
  templateUrl: 'unitmap.html'
})
export class UnitmapComponent {
  private UnitLocal: string;
  private UnitEndereco: string;

  constructor(private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator) {
    this.UnitLocal = this.getMap();
    this.UnitEndereco = "Universidade Tiradentes, Aracaju";
  }

  navToMaps() {
    console.log('Navegando para mapas');
    this.launchNavigator.navigate(this.UnitEndereco);
  }
}
```

When I run the app through the browser I'm able to get the console log, so I'm assuming the button references navToMaps correctly.

Comment: Are you using Ionic 4 or Ionic 3? And what's your Angular version?

Comment: Ionic 3 with Angular 5.2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned you are using Ionic 3 and Angular 5( Check your ionic.config.json file Your project type must be **ionic-angular** ), and you seem to be using the plugin whose **@ionic-native/launch-navigator**  whose version>=5.0.0 which is supported for Ionic 4 and Angular 6 and the project type **angular**.

You need to use the lower version of the native plugin for the application to work correctly.

Uninstall the plugin first

```
npm uninstall @ionic-native/launch-navigator
```

and install the proper version for your project type.

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/launch-navigator@4.20.0
```

And since you are not using Angular 6, you don't need to append **ngx** and the end of the import.

Like below

```
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-native/launch-navigator';
```

And also, don't forget to add the plugin to your app module's provider array.

**Reference** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54474247/6617276

Comment: I made this changes, but still nothing happen when I click the button. This card is a component, should I put the Launch Navigator on components.module.ts provider array? I tried this and nothing happened

Comment: And when I run the app through the browser I got this message when I click the button: "Ionic Native: tried calling LaunchNavigator.navigate, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html" 

But, again, when I run on a real device nothing happens.

Comment: My Android version is 8.1.1. But it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Did you try debugging on the real device? If you don't know how to debug on the real device , Follow this link https://ionic.zone/debug/remote-debug-your-app#android. You will get to know what error you are getting when you click the button.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about this, I'll try this later when I get home

Comment: Thank you for the help! I solved! I changed the @ionic-native/launch-navigator plugin version, but forgot to change the cordova plugin too, so they were incompatible. I installed cordova plugin version 4.2.0 and it finally worked

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with lower version but it is not working due to ionic/angular compatibility. And I have tried with v5.0.0 but the issue is unresolved. Then I have debug with android code and I found some setting in **AndroidManifest.xml** file as followed,

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
...
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
...
```

After **Android11** query required a special permission, It is throwing **NameNotFoundException** exception while checking packages applicable to open the map (related applications installed in your mobile device). You can find detail on following link, [NameNotFoundException when calling getPackageInfo on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345805/namenotfoundexception-when-calling-getpackageinfo-on-android-11)

Thanks.