# Javascript : Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

when I added BLE plugins in ionic project after i create some code for BLE scan after i run my application on andriod device then it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" from vendor.js.

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble';

ionViewDidEnter() {
      console.log('ionViewDidEnter');
      this.scan();
    }

    scan() 
    {
      this.setStatus('Scanning for Bluetooth LE Devices');
      this.devices = [];  // clear list

      this.ble.scan([], 5).subscribe(
        device => this.onDeviceDiscovered(device), 
        error => this.scanError(error)
      );

      setTimeout(this.setStatus.bind(this), 5000, 'Scan complete');
    }
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Could you add the code that causes the error to the post?

Comment: @JuhoRutila i have added type script code.

Comment: Can you specify your ionic  framework version as well as the ionic-native ble plugin version?

Comment: cli packages: (C:\Users\techbrain\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0

System:

    Node : v10.15.3
    npm  : 6.9.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
 
cordova-plugin-ble-central 1.2.2 "BLE"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" Error from Ionic-native VideoEditor Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467262/getting-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ionic 3 and maybe you are using ionic 4 plugins in ionic 3. So just remove the plugin and install this plugin.

click [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ble/)

Let me know it working or not.